# Finding similarity dissimilarity between different groups of vectors

Tags: machine-learning, python, data-visualization, word2vec, matplotlib

Suppose I need to combine or group together set of vectors in one area and another group in other areas, however I need to place these groups in a plot so they are scattered in the screen per similarity or dissimilarity.

- the vectors are actually word2vec, therefore each group is sentence
- I thought of adding individual vectors in each group, (word vectors) but how it will represent similar words in different groups.
- the next step is to plot this in Python (preferably) or R.

Attached is an conceptual graph of what am trying to do.[image]

- OK, let say I have Group 1: consists of 3 vectors, Group 2: 4
  vectors, Group 3: 2 vectors. between group 1 and 2 for example, 1
  vector is similar, now I need to find similarities between the groups
  as I need the vectors to remain enclosed in groups. Hope the image
  attached can help